# StyleCop Visual Studio Snippets

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop

I'm looking for some Visual Studio snippets for implementing style cop rules.

For instance when style cop returns an error saying my code needs a documentation header it would be useful to have a snippet that creates this header for me.

Has anyone got any snippets for implementing resolution to stylecop rules?

Comment: I can't see why this isn't a real question btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best way to automatically resolve stylecop errors: http://www.codeplex.com/StyleCopForReSharper

You'll need resharper, obviously

Answer (score 3):

I use GhostDoc for the header comments that you are referring to in your example. It works flawlessly. [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well...

In terms of documentation header try typing /// on the line preceeding a declaration.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't attempt to auto populate the summary and parameter elements in the same way GhostDoc does.